# Spawn Waves of Multiple Enemies in Multiple Locations

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I found a basic Spawner [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1326939/multiple-enemy-wave-spawners.html) and made some modifications. For some reason I can't access my own created class. Any ideas? I am getting errors in the following lines saying that the variables derived from the enemies list are inaccessible, i.e. line 60-63 **enemies.enemyCount**, **enemies.enemy** & **enemies.enemyRate**.

I want to be able to spawn multiple enemies (objects) in multiple locations (4 pre-defined locations) and only spawn the next wave if all enemies are killed:

```
public class WaveSystem : MonoBehaviour
{

    public static int EnemiesAlive = 0;

    public Wave[] waves;

    public Transform spawnPoint;

    public float timeBetweenWaves = 5f;
    public float countdown = 2f;

    //public float timeBetweenEnemies = 0.5f;

    public Text waveCountdownText;
    public Text wavesText;

    public List<EnemyBlueprint> enemies;

    private int waveIndex = 0;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (EnemiesAlive > 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (countdown <= 0f)
        {
            StartCoroutine(SpawnWave());
            countdown = timeBetweenWaves;
            return;
        }

        countdown -= Time.deltaTime;

        countdown = Mathf.Clamp(countdown, 0f, Mathf.Infinity);

        waveCountdownText.text = string.Format("{0:00.00}", countdown);

        wavesText.text = (waveIndex + 1) + "/" + waves.Length;
    }

    IEnumerator SpawnWave()
    {
        Wave wave = waves[waveIndex];

        for (int i = 0; a < wave.waveCount; i++)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f / wave.waveRate);

            for (int i = 0; i < enemies.enemyCount; i++)
            {
                SpawnEnemy(enemies.enemy);
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f / enemies.enemyRate);
            }
        }

        waveIndex++;

        if (waveIndex == waves.Length)
        {
            this.enabled = false;
        }
    }

    void SpawnEnemy(GameObject enemy)
    {
        Instantiate(enemy, spawnPoint.position, spawnPoint.rotation);
        EnemiesAlive++;
    }



    [System.Serializable]
    public class EnemyBlueprint
    {

        public GameObject enemy;
        public int enemyCount;
        public float enemyRate;
    }

    [System.Serializable]
    public class Wave
    {
        public EnemyBlueprint[] enemyWave;
        public int waveCount;
        public float waveRate;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

enemies is a list following its defintion `public List<EnemyBlueprint> enemies;`  , so when you write:

```
for (int i = 0; i < enemies.enemyCount; i++)
```

It is an error, 
In anyway you have to refactor your code with enemies

may be you should want to write:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < enemies.Count; i++)
        {
            SpawnEnemy(enemies[i].enemy);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f / enemies[i].enemyRate);
        }
```